# Makefile Selecting type of compilation

Tags: c++, makefile

How can I make it so that I can use the commands like `make debug` or `make release`, such that they both invoke the set of rules below but with different compilation flags (e.g. -g for debug and -DNDEBUG for release)?

```
# Object Files
OBJECTS         := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/,$(SOURCEFILES:.cpp=.o))

compile: $(OUTPUT) $(MAIN)

$(OUTPUT):
    @mkdir $(BUILDDIR)

$(MAIN): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS) -o $(OUTPUTMAIN) $(OBJECTS)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: debug release

debug:
    ... Compile with debug flags ...

release:
    ... Compile with release flags ...
```

Comment: I use Netbeans IDE (version 8.2 was the last version for C++) to first create a project makefile and then customize it for further needs. It creates a Makefile, Makefile-Debug, Makefile-Release and the appropriate version is called depending on whether the user calls make with debug configuration or release configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not difficult, just use [target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
debug: CXXFLAGS += -g -whatever

release:  CXXFLAGS += -DNDEBUG -otherstuff

debug release: $(OBJECTS)
    link things...
```

But there's a problem with your design. You build an object `foo.o` with either the `debug` flags or the `release` flags, but either way you name it `foo.o` and put it in the same build directory. So later on, when you build, say `release`, and there's a `foo.o` already there, Make will happily use it. See the problem? I suggest you have two build directories, one for `debug` and one for `release`; there are other ways, but you must decide before you tinker with the makefile.